# Get mailbox folder permissions for "remote" mailboxes

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, exchange-server

I'm using PowerShell commandlets to extract MailboxFolderPermissions.
I'm using **Get-MailboxfolderStatistics** to get list of folders for particular mailbox and then **Get-MailboxfolderPermission** to get permissions for all available folders.

All is working fine for mailboxes hosted locally on Exchange server I'm connected to.
But in the same domain there is another Exchange server and mailboxes hosted on it are also listed when invoking Get-Mailbox on the first one.

When I try to run **Get-MailboxfolderStatistics** or **Get-MailboxfolderPermission** for such "remote" mailbox I'm getting en error:

For **Get-MailboxFolderStatistics** cmdlet:

`Unable to retrieve mailbox folder statistics for mailbox xxxxxxx@xxxxxx.local. Failure: Error code -2146233088 occurred with message Cannot open mailbox /o=xxxxxxxx/ou=Exchange Administrative Group (FYDIBOHF23SPDLT)/cn=Configuration/cn=Servers/cn=EXCH2013/cn=Microsoft System Attendant..
    + CategoryInfo: ReadError: (:) [Get-MailboxFolderStatistics],MailboxFolderStatisticsException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : BE037E6,Microsoft.Exchange.Management.Tasks.GetMailboxFolderStatistics
    + PSComputerName: xxxxxxxxxxx`

For **Get-MailboxFolderPermission** cmdlet:

`Cannot open mailbox /o=xxxxxxxx/ou=Exchange Administrative Group (FYDIBOHF23SPDLT)/cn=Configuration/cn=Servers/cn=EXCH2013/cn=Microsoft System Attendant.
+ CategoryInfo: NotSpecified: (0:Int32) [Get-MailboxFolderPermission], ConnectionFailedTransientException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : A44BD817,Microsoft.Exchange.Management.StoreTasks.GetMailboxFolderPermission
+ PSComputerName: xxxxxxxxxxx`

Does anyone know what could the cause of above errors?

Is it possible to list permissions for remote mailbox folders?

Any help is really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

connect remote exchange server via ps session https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd335083(v=exchg.160).aspx

Comment: Thanks, for your suggestion. I know that I can connect to Exchange using ps session, and I'm doing it connecting to the first Exchange server from above description. The problem is that because of security policy I can't connect to the second one using this method. I can only access these mailboxes through first Exchange server, and this is the problem :( Do you have any other suggestions?